# Unity Build and Run aab file - nothing happens

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-instant-apps, ondemand, addressables

I am using unity addressables for on-demand packs and also using google instant play plugin to build an instant app. I am using the unity's Build Settings -> Build and Run with my device connected. I have developer debugging enabled and the device is connected via usb. The aab file is built and saved on my local machine and when the build completes, nothing happens on the device. Shouldn't the game just start on the phone? When I search the phone, the app is also not anywhere to be found.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does `adb devices` list the device?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes it does

Comment: Is there anything in the editor log that gives any clues? Usually it would build the aab, generate a suitable apk for the device from that, install it, and run it. Maybe instant play interferes with that process. You could try using bundletool to generate the apk and install it that way. If that also fails it may give some information about why.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thank you for the quick reply. The editor console says that it was successfull. When I use the bundletool, the apk parts are created. Though I am not sure what to install. It gives me error: "Please select all split APK parts!"

Comment: Not sure where that error is coming from. https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool Should be able to do `bundletool buildapks --connected-device ...` then `bundletool install-apks --apks=<output file from previous command>`

Comment: @RetiredNinja, the error above shows as a pop up on the phone. I actually manually moved the files to the phone and hit install on the apk. Did not use the bundle tool install-apks - that command actually also does nothing - the app still doesn't start on the device nor is installed. Maybe I am just using the command wrong. Need to play around with it.

Comment: Might be easier to just upload the bundle to Google Play in a test track and install it from there.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, thanks again for the answers. Google play does work (the apk can be downloaded and run on device). However, I am having some run-time errors and that is why I want to run that on a device localy to speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

So here is more of a workaround for this problem. The real solution needs to come I believe from either Unity or Google teams.

**FIX:**

1. Go to File -> Build settings -> player settings
2. Change the Company Name: com.yourname.currentname (to something else). Let's say: com.yourname.currentname2. And do the same for the packagename under "Other Settings".
3. Build and Run (having the device connected via USB and USB debugging enabled)

It should work. If still doesn't, make sure you uninstall your game (assuming you had it installed before on the device). If not installed, install it from the google play store or from an older apk, open the app info and clear all cache and data. Then uninstall it. Try the above steps for the fix.

On my side, I already had a published google play store app and now building an instant app for the same build. I uploaded a few instant app versions on the play store and installed them on the device. At that point I am not sure how google play handles the different versions (installed and instant one) and something terribly gets messed up. Is it caching some files somewhere? So aiming at a clean state is the key.